# Is the representation $\mathbf{N}\oplus\bar{\mathbf{N}}$ of $SU(N)$ real or pseudo-real?

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $N \geq 3$ be an integer. Let us call $\mathbf{N}$ its fundamental representation, and let $\bar{\mathbf{N}}$ be its complex conjugated representation.

Is the direct sum  $\mathbf{N}\oplus\bar{\mathbf{N}}$ real or pseudo-real ?

Comment: The similarity transformation interchanging 1-2 spaces suggests *just* pseudoreal. If you took N = 3, you could convince yourself by explicit calculation that this rep is pseudoreal, not real.